# $_GET returns nothing

Tags: php, .htaccess, url-routing

I am trying to build an routing using php for the first time.

I want the link like this:

```
http://localhost/controller/action
```

This is my .htaccess file:

```
Options +FollowSymLinks
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule ^([a-zA-Z]*)/?([a-zA-Z]*)?/?([a-zA-Z0-9]*)?/?$ index.php?controller=$1&action=$2&id=$3 [NC,L]
```

I want to access `$_GET['controller']` and `$_GET['action']` but it gives - undefined index error.

`var_dump($_GET)` returns

> array (size=0)
>       empty

Comment: Having you tried disallowing empty groups? E.g. `([a-zA-Z]+)` instead of `([a-zA-Z]*)`?

Comment: I tried it just now. Still have the same problem.

Comment: maybe you should turn MultiViews option off see this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49410365/php-file-not-able-to-access-get-variable-after-htaccess-rewrite-rule/49411610#49411610

Comment: i turned it off. Still have the same problem

Comment: @ÁlvaroGonzález paste how you add it

Answer (score 0):

The problems is, that your regex is less strict and the slashes (but not the last one) must not be optional for this functioning properly. you also should escape the slashes.

```
Options +FollowSymLinks
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule ^([a-zA-Z]+)\/([a-zA-Z]+)\/([a-zA-Z0-9]+)\/?$ index.php?controller=$1&action=$2&id=$3 [NC,L]
```

Comment: try your youurl.com/aaa/bbb/ccc and tell me what you get with print_r()

Comment: i get this error:
404 Not Found
The requested URL /aaa/bbb/ccc was not found on this server.

Comment: try ^(.*)$ index.php?var=$1 and tell me the result

Comment: It returns :
404 Not Found for localhost/aaa

Comment: is mod rewrite installed?

Comment: I enabled it and tried localhost/aaa , it gave me a 404 error. But when i try localhost/?aaa , it gives Array ( [aaa] => )